# Powershell: Count within foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, count

I have a Powershell script that queries AD user certificates. I'd like to check and inform the user if his VPN certificate is going to expire soon. The script runs fine so far, but I have some instances where the user already has 2 VPN certificates and I don't want to notify if this is the case (in Script on step "### Execute next steps if count is less then 2"). I've tried to add ".count" to some of the variables, but since it's within the foreach, it's always giving me a "1" as a match. I have no clue how to achieve this, please help. Here's the script:

```
param (
[string]$queryDN       = '...DC=com',
[string]$VPNcertname   = 'VPN OID',
[int]$days             = 14
)

# Make decision what to check
$userpath          = $queryDN
$cert2check        = $VPNcertname

# Begin script
$users = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $userpath).distinguishedName
foreach ($dude in $users) {
 $user = Get-ADUser $dude -Property Certificates
 $Certificatelist = $user.Certificates | foreach {
  New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_
 }
   ForEach($cert in $Certificatelist){
    $querycertificate = if($cert.EnhancedKeyUsageList.Where({$_.FriendlyName -eq $cert2check})){
### Execute next steps if count is less then 2
     $expirationDate = $Cert.NotAfter
       if ($expirationDate -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays($days)) {
        write-host The $cert2check certificate for user: $user.UserPrincipalName`, expires: $expirationDate. This is less than: $days days and should be changed soon.
      }
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `if ($user.certificates.count -ge 2) {...}`? Also you seem to need to inform if *all* of the user's certs are expired or close to be expired, so just collect maximum of `$expirationDate` and corresponding cert, and trigger warning if only that date is too close to expiration.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work like I meant to. Sorry, I forgot to mention: The users have couple of certificates; "usually" 2 Secure Email and 1 VPN cert. The "$user.certificates.count" gives me the total amount, but I need only the VPN amount. I query only the VPN certs in the $querycertificate, but since I'm already in the foreach I always get the result for one - the current object.

Comment: Again - you list all certs, then select only those that are for VPN, THEN check how many of them you received. `$CertList2=$Certificatelist|where {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq $cert2check}; if ($CertList2.count -gt 1) {...}` In case `.EnhancedKeyUsageList` is an array, use `-contains` in where-filter.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vesper. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66441523/powershell-count-within-foreach-loop#comment117490164_66441523) was exactly what I was looking for:

```
$CertList2=$Certificatelist|where {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq $cert2check}; if ($CertList2.count -gt 1) {...}
```